# Declare class variable as conforming to Swift protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

In Swift, how would I declare a variable that explicitly states that it conforms to some protocol? The objective-c equivalent would be `@property id<NSObject>`
From my understanding, doing this:

`var a: NSObject`

declares a variable that is of type NSObject protocol but I don't to do that, I want to declare a variable of type `AnyObject` that conforms. I'm also interested in finding out how to declare an array of objects in which each object conforms to that protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really no need for `AnyObject` here; if all you care about is conformance to a protocol `Proto`, you can simply write `var a: Proto`. (In some cases your protocol may use `Self` or other things that require it to be used as a generic constraint; you would then use `class C<T: Proto> { var a: T }`.

Comment: Ah so `var a: Proto` is specifying conformance? Interesting, I would have assumed it was a variable of type Proto.

Comment: Since `Proto` is a protocol type, being "of type Proto" doesn't really mean anything other than conformance. Unfortunately there is the `Self` caveat which you'll see in some cases that prevents you from using this syntax. I expect this might change in later updates to Swift.

Answer (score 3):

The `NSObject` *protocol* is imported into Swift as `NSObjectProtocol` (due to a name conflict with the `NSObject` *class*), therefore, it would be

```
var a: NSObjectProtocol
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 it's possible an easier way. You can declare variable of some class conforming to protocol at the same time. You can do it like this:

```
var someVar: ClassA & ProtocolA & ProtocolB
```

Comment: Like the accepted answer, this does not work with any protocol that has Self or Associated Type requirements